# Loop video from the selected duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I can't make the video to loop after 2 seconds. It should loop after the video pauses. I'm not sure hot to make it happen. The functionality works fine, but doesn't loop.

```js
function playVideo() {
  var starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
  var endtime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
  var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
      this.pause();
      //  SHOULD LOOP HERE? 
    }
  }, false);

  //suppose that video src has been already set properly
  video.load();
  video.play();
  try {
    video.currentTime = starttime;
  } catch (ex) {
    //handle exceptions here
  }
}

playVideo();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the video to immediately go back to the start after 2 seconds and continue playing, simply set `currentTime` back to `0` within the `timeupdate` hanler. Your current logic setting `currentTime` is in the wrong place, and the `try/catch` around it is unnecessary. Try this:

```js
var starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
var endtime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');

function playVideo() {
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
      this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
    }
  }, false);

  video.load();
  video.play();
}

playVideo();
```

```html
<div>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks dude! I need to functionality one that plays the video fror 2 seconds (on loop) and the other one till the end (on loop)

Can I use this code and make to functions?

Comment: Sure. To loop when the video ends research the `ended` event. The logic to restart the video is the same as the above, thoug

Comment: Rory, would you be able to help me with this question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167309/play-video-in-loop-with-different-timing-and-function

Answer (score 0):

You can put this there at your code:

```
function playVideo() {
  var starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
  var endtime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
  var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
      this.pause();
      starttime = 0;
      playVideo();
    }
  }, false);

  //suppose that video src has been already set properly
  video.load();
  video.play();
  try {
    video.currentTime = starttime;
  } catch (ex) {
    //handle exceptions here
  }
}

playVideo();
```

Comment: This works, but note that the end result is that you add a new `timeupdate` event handler in every loop