# Play video in loop with different timing and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have 2 function which play the same video but with different timing.
I can't play make the function to work properly.

Looks like the function doesn't reset the other function

I tried to change variables names but still change the timing on click.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');

function playShortVideo() {
  var starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
  var endtime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
      this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
    }
  }, false);

  video.load();
  video.play();
}

function playFullVideo() {
var starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
var endtime = 24; // stop at 2 seconds
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
      this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
    }
  }, false);

  video.load();
  video.play();
}

//play short video by default
playShortVideo();


//CLICK events 
var btnshort = $('.shortvideo');
var btnfull = $('.fullvideo');
btnshort.click(function() {
  
  playShortVideo();
});

btnfull.click(function() {
  playFullVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>
 
</div>

<button class="shortvideo">play 2 secs only</a><br>

<button class="fullvideo">loop full video</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the listener is still there, you need to [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) it.

Remember, in order to remove it, you can't use anonymous function as callback so I turned it into defined function.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');
const playShort = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 2) {
    this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
  }
};
const playFull = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 24) {
    this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
  }
};

function playShortVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false);

  video.load();
  video.play();
}

function playFullVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false);
  
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

//play short video by default
playShortVideo();


//CLICK events 
var btnshort = $('.shortvideo');
var btnfull = $('.fullvideo');
btnshort.click(function() {

  playShortVideo();
});

btnfull.click(function() {
  playFullVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>

</div>

<button class="shortvideo">play 2 secs only</a><br>

<button class="fullvideo">loop full video</button>
```

And here is the approach for starting the video at 49 sec (60 > 49 + 10)

```js
const shortStartTime = 49;
const shortDuration = 10;

var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');
const playShort = function() {
  if (this.currentTime > (shortStartTime + shortDuration)) {
    this.currentTime = shortStartTime; // change time index here
  }
};
const playFull = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 24) {
    this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
  }
};

function playShortVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false);

  video.load();
  video.currentTime = shortStartTime;
  video.play();
}

function playFullVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false);
  
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

//play short video by default
playShortVideo();


//CLICK events 
var btnshort = $('.shortvideo');
var btnfull = $('.fullvideo');
btnshort.click(function() {
  playShortVideo();
});

btnfull.click(function() {
  playFullVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>

</div>

<button class="shortvideo">play 2 secs only</a><br>

<button class="fullvideo">loop full video</button>
```

Comment: Sure :) Happy to help.. @user173420 if it answer your question, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so it may help to other people

Comment: What would you do to don't make them Jumping?

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"?

Comment: Do you know why is giving me  Uncaught (in promise) DOMException ???

error on   videoClient.play(); ?

Comment: I need some context. (device, brwoser) I don't get this error on my mac / Chrome (desktop). I see that you did add `muted` to the `video` tag, but maybe you forgot it in your app? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742427/863110

Comment: The error shows only when I refresh the page! really weird.

Comment: Hello, how do I play this video from 50 to 60 seconds? 

https://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/0b5n8kgy/8/

Comment: Not sure gives me  Uncaught (in promise) DOMException. DO you know why?

Comment: what was wrong? I found out why I had that error. I was calling .play() call twice :-)

Comment: I added `video.currentTime = 50;` in `playShortVideo` function. Also, changed the check to `this.currentTime > 59` because `this.currentTime >= 60` always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're attaching a timeUpdate event listener multiple times.
You either need to use one-only or delete it before attaching a new one.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');
var listener;
var starttime = 0;
var endtime = 2;

function updateVideo(e) {
  if (e.target.currentTime >= endtime) {
    e.target.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
  }
}

function playShortVideo() {
  starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
  endtime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
  if (!listener) {
    listener = video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateVideo, false);
  }
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

function playFullVideo() {
  starttime = 0; // start at 0 seconds
  endtime = 24; // stop at 2 seconds
  if (!listener) {
    listener = video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateVideo, false);
  }
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

//play short video by default
playShortVideo();


//CLICK events 
var btnshort = $('.shortvideo');
var btnfull = $('.fullvideo');
btnshort.click(function() {

  playShortVideo();
});

btnfull.click(function() {
  playFullVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>

</div>

<button class="shortvideo">play 2 secs only</a><br>

<button class="fullvideo">loop full video</button>
```